# Hangman game check if type of guess is not string doesn't work

Tags: javascript

This is the hangman game. It's a simple game from js book for beginners. I try to add more checks to what the user enters. I put a else if typeof guess !== 'string' but doesn't work.

When I enter a number or a symbol # the code goes into the -- one more life: guessesNr--, and not in alert("Please enter a single letter!");

Please someone tell me how to do it, because it's beyond my knowledge why doesn't work with my logic.

```js
var words = [
 "javascript",
 "monkey",
 "amazing",
 "pancake"
 ];

var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

//create an empty array called answerArray and fill it 
//with underscores (_) to match the number
//of letters in the word
var answerArray = [];

for( var i=0; i < word.length; i++) {
 answerArray[i] = "_";
}

//every time the player guesses a
//correct letter, this value will 
//be decremented (reduced) by 1
var remainingLetters = word.length;
var guessesNr = 4;
var isHit = false;

while((remainingLetters > 0) && (guessesNr > 0)) {
 // Show the player their progress
 alert("The word is from " + word.length + " letters " + answerArray.join(" "));
 // Take input from player
 var guess = prompt("Guess a letter");

 // if the player clicks the Cancel button, then guess will be null
 if(guess===null) {
  // break to exit the loop
  break;
  //ensuring that guess is exactly one letter
 } else if(guess.length !== 1) {
  alert("Please enter a single letter!");
 } else if(typeof guess !== 'string') {
  alert("Please enter only letters!");
 } else {
  for(var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
   if(word[j] === guess) {
    // sets the element at index j, from word, 
    // of answerArray to guess
    answerArray[j] = guess;
    remainingLetters--;
    isHit = true;
   
   } 
  }
  if(!isHit) {
   guessesNr--;
   alert("You have " + guessesNr + " more lives");
   if(guessesNr === 0) {
    alert("No more lives");
    break;
   }
   
  }
  
 }
 
}

//alert(answerArray.join(" "));
alert("Great job! The answer was " + word);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The return value from 'prompt' is a string.** A string may contain almost any character, including letters, symbols and numbers. In your case, you're checking for a *string*, not for *letters*. So:

- "abcd1234" is a string;
- 1234 is an integer (notice the lack of quotes): `typeof 1234 == "number"`
- "1234" is a string. `typeof "1234" == "string"`

So you should be checking for a *string made up only of letters*. There are dozens of possible ways for doing this, you may do it easily with a regular expression, for example:

```
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
if (!guess.match(letters)) alert("Please enter only letters!");
```

And if you want only ONE letter, try the same with:

```
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]$/;
```

Regular expressions are very powerful, my advice is you read more about them. Hope I've helped!

Comment: Wow. I was correct when I said that this is beyond my knowledge :). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The test for letters is wrong:

```
 if(typeof guess !== 'string') {
```

This is a data type test, and will always fail, since `prompt` always returns a string when it is not `null`.

Instead you could do:

```
if(guess.toUpperCase() === guess.toLowerCase()) {
```

Comment: My friend I want to check if is a letter and not a number or symbol $. I didn't think yet of uppercase but that is a good point. But if I enter now a number nothing happens.

Comment: Yes I turned it around: it you put `===` then it checks whether it is *not*  a letter.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check whether `gues` variable a number, you can do it in this way:

```
if(isNaN(Number(guess)) === false) {
  ...
}
```

Where [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)  is a function, that determines whether a value is NaN or not.